# magento 1.9.1.0 change product details on colour change

Tags: php, magento

My magento version is 1.9.1.0 and using shopper theme(custom)
I've successfully implemented colour swatch on my theme but now client wants on colour change products will be change means product name details etc
She given me the ref url  http://www.scarves.com/green-acrylic-london-tartan-knit-scarf

I could not find any clue or extension that support this functionality.

Anyone can have knowledge please share

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change every Details, You can use magento Extension SCP.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/simple-configurable-products.html